# Charts BarChartView custom ChartYAxis

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi am implementing charts framework Barchartview I want to customize the Yaxis here is my code

```
ChartYAxis *leftAxis = _chartView_fairway_hit.leftAxis;
leftAxis.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f];
leftAxis.labelCount = 5;
//    leftAxis.valueFormatter = [[ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter alloc] initWithFormatter:leftAxisFormatter];
leftAxis.labelPosition = YAxisLabelPositionOutsideChart;
leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.25;
leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0;
leftAxis.axisMaximum = 100;
```

However, the above code is giving me the Y axis like 0 20 40 60 80 100. I am expecting the output like 0 25 50 75 100

Comment: can you give me link of barchartview sdk/framework ?

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts @NiravKotecha

Comment: leftAxis.granularity = ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `leftAxis.granularity = 25.0;` and check it.

see the below image. it's look like that way..

[image]